# calling another http request upon changing page

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, windows-phone-8, here-api

I'm working with windows phone apps and I'm using here rest places api for my data and i retrieving data as json that give me information about location nearby like this

```
position: [ 37.77704 , -122.39494 ]
distance: 1241
title: Caltrain-San Francisco
averageRating: 0.0
category: { Public transport }
icon: http://download.vcdn.nokia.com/p/d/places2/icons/categories/11.icon
vicinity: 700 4th St<br/>San Francisco, CA 94107
having: [ ]
type: urn:nlp-types:place
href: http://demo.places.nlp.nokia.com/places/v1/places/8409q8yy-a7395cccbfc4474ba469f3ddc03e041b;context=Zmxvdy1pZD00OWQxZDY0Zi0zODc5LTVlNDAtOWY4ZC04ZGFmNWMyMGZhZDFfMTM4OTg4NDQxMzUxNV8wXzM1MjkmcmFuaz0w?app_id=lp3VaO8uhOFe0akZ4J1m&app_code=JwL7MNaSarML92oqEDshAg
id: 8409q8yy-a7395cccbfc4474ba469f3ddc03e041b
```

and i notice that if i open

```
href: http://demo.places.nlp.nokia.com/places/v1/places/8409q8yy-a7395cccbfc4474ba469f3ddc03e041b;context=Zmxvdy1pZD00OWQxZDY0Zi0zODc5LTVlNDAtOWY4ZC04ZGFmNWMyMGZhZDFfMTM4OTg4NDQxMzUxNV8wXzM1MjkmcmFuaz0w?app_id=lp3VaO8uhOFe0akZ4J1m&app_code=JwL7MNaSarML92oqEDshAg
```

i will go into other page that contain much detailed information about that location, so how can i get all of this data?the general and detailed data from that href

method that i using to get general data is using this

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
Uri uri = new Uri(transportURL1 + latitude + "%2C" + longitude + transportURL2, UriKind.Absolute);
client.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) =>
{
   if (e.Error == null)
    {
      RootObject result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(e.Result);
                        hereRestProperty = new ObservableCollection<Item>(result.results.items);
   }
   else
   {
       MessageBox.Show(e.Error.ToString());
   }
};
client.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
```

so my app scenario is mainpage showing general location data and when I tap one of the location data it will navigate to detailpage that contain information from that href

how to do that?

edit: my work around is getting href and using that href to calling http request but i have no idea how to do all that...

edit2: after looking around I come up with idea of having mainpage with list of general information and if I click into one of the item in list it will navigate me to detailpage that will request from that href but i just don't know how to execute that in mvvm aproach...

Comment: The data you get back from your query to the service is completely defined by the person/company/site that is giving you the data. You need to contact them or check their API documentation.

Comment: well what I mean is how to get the href and put it as another http request

Comment: Do you want to make the HTTP request yourself, or pass it off to a browser to open for your user?

Comment: make http request myself

Comment: You need to provide more information. What exactly do you want to do? You are already making an HTTP request to get some JSON data from a server, do the same thing with this URL. If you're already doing that, are you having problems displaying it on the screen? What is the problem you're having? Please be clear about what you need. Also, edit the title of your post to reflect your question as it's not very clear either.

Comment: sorry for to general question, i already edited since overnight i already get some work around idea but don't know how to execute it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is safe to assume that you are trying to add value to your app by adding a places feature, I would suggest that for **Windows Phone 8** you would be better off launching **HERE Maps** directly using the [HERE Maps Launchers API](http://developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Lumia/#!maps-and-navigation/here-launchers.html)

For example, if your app is about *hiking trails* it would make sense to add a feature for finding details of places to eat or stay near that hiking trail - but you wouldn't need to create your own code to request, format and display the in-depth places data, just fire up the Maps app already on the device (passing in the `href` from the initial REST request if necessary). The advantage of doing this is threefold, firstly you can add this feature in four lines of code, secondly the user is presented with the places information in a familiar format, and finally information is retrieved from the device itself which alleviates the need to make additional HTTP requests.

One or more of the following tasks may be useful:

- `ExploremapsShowPlaceTask` allows you to start the Maps application with the map centered to a place shown in the map.
- `ExploremapsSearchPlacesTask` allows you to start the Maps application with the search view.
- `ExploremapsExplorePlacesTask` allows you to start the Maps application where the nearby places of interest are shown.
- `PlacesShowDetailsByLocationTask` allows you to start the Maps application with the places view for the selected place.
- `PlacesShowDetailsByIdHrefTask` allows you to start the Maps application with the places view for the selected place.

Note that if **HERE Maps** is not installed  on the **Windows Phone 8** device, the user will be directed to download it for free from the app store.

Comment: well, I don't want my app depend to much to other apps and in this case if I using this then if someone just don't want to use here maps (because certain reason) then my app will be useless

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from offering a limited fallback option in the case that a user: a) doesn't have the **HERE Maps** app  b) doesn't want to download several MBs of data at this time (e.g. due to limited bandwidth). In this case you _could_ attempt to display some information as retrieved from your original REST request. It should be noted that **HERE Maps** is FREE and comes pre-installed on **Nokia Lumias** which already accounts for over 80% of the WP8 market. Presumably if the user has already bought the phone they would be familiar with the standard maps app installed on it.

Comment: Actually over 90% according to [AdDuplex](http://www.gsmarena.com/90_of_all_shipped_wp8_devices_are_nokia_lumia-news-7008.php)